# JqueryUI Draggable scroll is not working downwards inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Can you help me to enable the scrolling down in when you dragging down an element because, in the iframe is not working when you scroll down without mouse.

```css
  #iframeBox{
   height:5000px;

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div style="height: 178px; border: 1px solid #000;">

</div>



    <div id="container2">
      <iframe id="iframeBox" src="http://slm-promo.web.sd-svc.net/COA0036/coateschallenge"  width="100%" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
    </div>




 

<div style="height: 1000px; border: 1px solid #000;">


</div>
```

you can click the full page and try to drag the image down and here's the code.

```js
 $(".draggables .item-container .item").draggable({
  revert: "invalid", 
  containment: "#selection",
  helper: "clone",
  scroll: true,
  scrollSensitivity: 100,
  scrollSpeed: 100,
  cursor: "move",
    });

    $(".droppables .item-container .item").droppable({
  accept: ".draggables .item-container .item",
  classes: {
   "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
   "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
   insertItem(this, ui.draggable );
  }
 });
```

Comment: tried <iframe scrolling="yes">?

Comment: yes, but I want to hide the scrollbar but it will scroll up and down.